# ReactJS: Llamar una función desde un componente a otro

Tags: reactjs

estoy construyendo un un sitio en react con tsx, quiero llamar una clase MyAccountLogin.service que es donde tengo los servicios con axios

y la necesito llamar desde el compontente padre que es MyAccount

Este es el código del servicio (Que está en una clase aparte)

```
    export class MyAccountLogin extends React.Component{


constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.Login = this.Login.bind(this);
}

Login(user: any) {
    const res =  axios.post(uri, user);
    console.log("res", res);
    return res;

  }}
```

Desde acá se llama al servicio en axios, pero el método lógin no lo reconoce

export class MyAccountLogin extends React.Component<{}, IState> {

```
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
}


handleSubmit(values: MyAccountLoginModel) {
    console.log(values);

    
    // aca intento consumir llamar el metodo login pero arroja error y previamente ya se importo en AccountServices

    AccountServices.Login(values).then( res => {
        const r = res;
    });
}
```

}

Así está la clase desde necesito llamar el método login
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola Cristian, bienvenido a stack overflow, te aconsejo que te pases por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el sitio web, por otro lado, te invito a que leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta pueda tener un buen formato y pueda llegar a muchas personas y asi poder obtener ayuda mas rápido

Comment: por otro lado, no subas imágenes de tu código, es tedioso tener que escribir todo tu código para poder responderte, cópialo y pégalo, será mas fácil para vos y para los usuarios q te lean, de mi parte te recomiendo q empieces a dejar de lado las clases en React y migres a los componentes funcionales para poder aprovechar sus beneficios como los hooks, y una ultima cosa, trata de agregar todo el código q sea necesario para q pueda entenderte, para ti puede ser obvio lo q hace, para los usuario no, trata de agregar lo q hace tu código, lo q intentas hacer y el resultado q obtienes y el q esperas

Comment: No se entiende qué quieres hacer. Muestras tanto en la imagen como en el "código" la misma clase.

Comment: @Jacobo ya se modificó y  explique un poco mas a detalle, es llamar desde la clase MyAccountLogin  el servicio que está en la otra clase que es un servicio con axios, es poder llamar las funciones de esa clase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que el error es que en el export default de tu componente AccountServices, cambialo a

```
const accountServices = new AccountServices();
export default accountServices ;
```